# reporting services 2008 R2 shows UAC for printing ActiveX after .NET 4.0 installation

Tags: printing, ssrs, uac

Installed the latest updates on the server.

Now every time I try to print from a reporting service website the UAC opens..

I already tried to reduce security within IE9 to the minimum, but with no success so far.

Any ideas?

Update:
I disabled UAC and now found out its a problem that it tries to install SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2 (again). During that Installation the file **rsclientprint-x86.inf** can not be copied. Thus this file couldn't be copied, printing works afterward for that specific page (until the page gets refreshed..)

Comment: Actually it can not be (only) because IE9 itself. that was installed already 1 month ago. but .NET 4 Client Profile and C++ Redistributables had been updated..

Comment: looks like the following article will solve the problem for me! [deploy printing for ssrs 2008 R2](http://datamanlv.blogspot.com/2011/05/sql-2008-r2-reporting-service-print.html)

Comment: i also tried to follow this instruction, but with no success..